# Hidden Service's Hostname Resets after reboot

Tags: linux, networking, debian, apache-http-server, tor

I run a Debian VM that runs TOR and apache2,

recently I set up a relay and a hidden service,

however when I restarted tor the hostname "reset", alteast thats what Firefox told me.

after, I delete the Hostname and Private Key and it worked, but the same issue was there.

How do I make it so the Hostname and private keys stay the same after a restart on TOR?

btw, my relay is "KounoKuriisbetboi", dont ask, and my hidden serive is http://toru7zlch3ib72fq.onion/, but this might change if I stop tor.

Also, I understand the fact I have a bunch of security issues, but its a cloud VM all the way in New York, I can easily destroy it and make a new one

EDIT: When I mean my hostname resets, the hostnames key is remade to somthing new!

Comment: What do you mean that the hostname "reset"? That description is rather vague. Exactly what happened?

Comment: @MichaelHampton To my understanding, it just remade my keys, thats why I get a new host and private key.

Comment: This also happens with relays when you edit there name, you regerate a new fingerprint. So, maybe somthing like that is happening? idk its most likey unrelated.